# how to access nsf file from linux and use database in window using java

Tags: java, file-io, lotus-notes

```
Updated Question
```

Hello friends,
I am updating the question, I am using jcifs api to access the .nsf file from the SUSE server, it's successfully accessed but when I am trying to pass this path to the getDatabase() method its unable to open the database I don't what the problem there as this directory and files are accessible as shared

```
SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);
```

here I check that whether the file is available or not right now give the static path in this

```
if(sFile.isFile()){
    Database database = s.getDatabase ("", sFile.getPath());
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If the customer is running a Lotus Domino server, you should not be attempting to access the databases as File objects.  You should be using something like this:

```
Database db = s.getDatbase("server name/organization name", "path/test.nsf"
```

You should get the "server name/organization name" string from the administrators of the Domino server, and the path should be relative to the Domino server's root data directory.  Or, you could use something like this:

```
DbDirectory dbDir = s.getDbDirectory("server name/organization name")
```

and then you can use the methods of the DbDirectory class to locate the specific database that you need.

**Edited to add more info:**

It could also be useful for you to know that the Lotus Notes API has had its own abstract filename format, implemented for more than 20 years.  This format looks like this:

```
"CN=Domino server name/O=organization name!!folder path/test.nsf"
```

If you use this format, then you can leave the first argument of getDatabase() blank even if the database is hosted on a Domino server.  The Notes APIs will take care of OS-specific format issues, however there is one thing that the APIs can't take care of for you: the path and file component are case-insensitive on Windows, but they are case-sensitive on Linux.  And thinking about that... this might even be related to your problem.  If the real filename is 'Test.nsf' instead of 'test.nsf' you would have a problem -- but I'm pretty certain that would be a NotesException rather than FileNotFoundException so it's probably not related.

Comment: The only useful purpose for opening a Notes database as a File seems to me backup. But even then there are lots of pitfalls. I'm still puzzled though, why would someone open a Notes database as a File??

Comment: He's actually not using the File object to open the NSF file.  He's just using it to try to convert an abstract filename into a system-specific filename.  But the reason for doing that is unclear to me.  I did note that he is using 'lotus/notes' in the path, rather than 'lotus/domino/data', so perhaps this is a local file -- but in that case the reference to running on Windows but referencing a file on SuSE server raised my suspcions that the file really isn't local and it may be on a SuSE-based Domino server.

Comment: @rhsatrhs you are right that I am trying to access the database from the domino server data directory. But didn't know more about this configuration any thing more thanks for the reply

Comment: @rhsatrhs one more thing can I open the database using smb api in java? Actually I need to open the .nsf database in core application

Comment: Ah... To end the confusion, could you please explain what you mean when you want to "open" the database? If you want to read structured information (e.g. documents), your only sensible way is to use the Notes API and the Domino Object Model in Java. On the other hand, if you want to read (meaningless) bytes, you can just open it as an ordinary file.

Comment: I want to open the .nsf file using Notes API not as normal file I am break at the access the .nsf file from notes/data directory from the linux suse server

Comment: Are you still getting FileNotFoundException?  Have you changed your code to use just the relative file name as a String instead of using getAbsolutePath?  And have you checked with a Notes client connected to the SuSE server to be sure that your relative path is correct?  SuSE filenames are case-sensitive, so you must have relative path exactly correct.  If your code is different now, please update your question with the latest info.

Comment: where can I get this thing/how can I find this? "CN=Domino server name/O=organization name!!folder path/test.nsf" format

Comment: The fully-qualified server name is the most basic thing you always need to connect to a Domino server.  Ask the sponsor of your project and/or the Domino Administrator to give it to you.  Better yet, as them to set you up with a Notes client and an account on the server.

Comment: I see that you have updated the question, but you did not answer what I asked above: are you still getting FileNotFoundException?  If not, what exception are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

in order to access the file on the other comuter you must have the right permissions for that so shared folder seems to be a good idea.
ofcourse, if you have the option to define some sort of server on the remote machine and save the file under his root you will be able to access the file without special permissions (example: define SFTP server on the remote machine, save the file under his root, connect from the user computer and take the file)

Comment: I am trying with the SmbFile of jcifs api to access the file. I am able to access it but as I pass SmbFile object path to the getDatabase() method its unable to open the database of .nsf file any idea. how to achieve this using SmbFile object?